# How to create tabs - Jquery or JSF

Tags: java, jquery, jsf, jsf-2

I want to create JSF page with tabs. Something like [this](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/tabPanel.jsf). But I wonder if I choose to do this with Jquery can I implement lazy loading - when I click a tab on the JSF page the content is generated when the tab is opened. Is it possible to implement lazy loading of tabs in pure JSF? And I suppose that I can easily implement AJAX in both cases.

Best wishes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note: If you want your tabs beans be Session Scope then read instructions in the buttom of the Answer...**

Since you are don't want to use any third party Libarary here is a PureJSF + jQuery example

**JSF + Jquery + Ajax Lazy Loading + View Scope Beans Example...**

B.T.W here is how it looks like eventually :

[image: JSF + Jquery Lazy Loading Tabs]

You can look at the web server console for the print outs of `@PostConstruct` and the `@PreDestroy` when you click on each tab...

The content of the tab  - the xhtml page and its bean will be loaded upon tab click (Lazy Loading) and will be destroyed upon click on other tab,

I suggest you to create a new project and slowly place all the files inside it and start playing and looking into it... its 100% working , but I placed some print outs just to see that it is really working...

The Example is very simple and straight forward....

First Of all go to [jQueryUI and download it(1.8.18)](http://jqueryui.com/download)

and place `jquery-1.7.1_.min.js` and `jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js` in `WebContent\resources\js` and `jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css` in `WebContent\resources\css`

Now to the other files...

**myTabs.xhtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
<h:head>
 <h:outputScript library="js" name="jquery-1.7.1_.min.js" target="head" />
 <h:outputScript library="js" name="jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js" target="head" />
 <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css" target="head"     />
 <h:outputScript library="js" name="mytabs.js" target="head" />
</h:head>
<h:body>

<f:view>
    <h:form prependId="false">
        <h:panelGroup id="tabs" layout="block">
            <ul>
                <c:forEach items="#{myTabs.tabs}" var="tab">
                    <li><a href="##{tab.tabid}" onclick="$('#button_#{tab.tabid}').click()">#{tab.tabid}</a></li>
                    <h:commandButton id="button_#{tab.tabid}" value="TabClick" action="#{myTabs.switchPages(tab.tabid)}" style="display:none">
                        <f:ajax render="tabs"></f:ajax>
                    </h:commandButton>  
                </c:forEach>
            </ul>

            <c:forEach items="#{myTabs.tabs}" var="tab">
                <h:panelGroup id="#{tab.tabid}" layout="block" rendered="#{tab.tabid eq myTabs.selectedTab}">
                    <ui:include src="#{tab.tabfilename}"></ui:include>
                </h:panelGroup>
            </c:forEach>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </h:form>
</f:view>
</h:body>
</html>
```

**MyTabs.java**

```
package pack;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class MyTabs{

@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    tabs = new ArrayList<MyTabObject>();
    tabs.add(new MyTabObject("tab1.xhtml", "tab1"));
    tabs.add(new MyTabObject("tab2.xhtml", "tab2"));
    tabs.add(new MyTabObject("tab3.xhtml", "tab3"));

}
String selectedTab="tab1";

public String getSelectedTab() {
    return selectedTab;
}

public void setSelectedTab(String selectedTab) {
    this.selectedTab = selectedTab;
}

public String switchPages(String selTab) {
    selectedTab = selTab;
    return "myTabs.xhtml";
}


List<MyTabObject> tabs;


public List<MyTabObject> getTabs() {
    return tabs;
}

public void setTabs(List<MyTabObject> tabs) {
    this.tabs = tabs;
}


}
```

**MyTabObject**

```
package pack;



public class MyTabObject{


String tabfilename;
String tabid;
public String getTabfilename() {
    return tabfilename;
}
public void setTabfilename(String tabfilename) {
    this.tabfilename = tabfilename;
}
public String getTabid() {
    return tabid;
}
public void setTabid(String tabid) {
    this.tabid = tabid;
}
public MyTabObject(String tabfilename, String tabid) {
    super();
    this.tabfilename = tabfilename;
    this.tabid = tabid;
}

}
```

**Tab1Page , (Tab2Page and Tab3Page are exactly the same , just change the number in all places)**

```
package pack;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.text.Format;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Tab1Page implements Serializable{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 254415216070877770L;
// Constants
public final static String hashKey = "tab1PageTab";
public String actionString = "";

@PostConstruct
public void post(){
  Format formatter;
  Date date = new Date();

  // Time formate 01:12:53 AM
  formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
  tabName = formatter.format(date);
    System.out.println("Tab1Page\t"+tabName+"\t@PostConstruct...");
}

@PreDestroy
public void destroy(){
  Format formatter;
  Date date = new Date();

  // Time formate 01:12:53 AM
  formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
  tabName = formatter.format(date);
    System.out.println("Tab1Page\t"+tabName+"\t@PreDestroy...");
}


String tabName;

public String getTabName() {
    return this.getClass().getName().substring(this.getClass().getName().lastIndexOf("."))+"\t"+tabName;
}
public void setTabName(String tabName) {
    this.tabName = tabName;
}

public String getActionString() {
    return actionString;
}

public void setActionString(String actionString) {
    this.actionString = actionString;
}

}
```

**tab1.xhtml (tab2.xhtml and tab3.xhtml are exactly the same - just replace the numbers)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" 
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">

<h:panelGroup>
    <h:form>
        <h:outputText value="#{tab1Page.tabName}" />
    </h:form>
</h:panelGroup>
</ui:composition>
```

and to the last file

**mytabs.js (place it in WebContent\resources\js)**

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $("#tabs").tabs();
});

$(window).load(function() {
    jsf.ajax.addOnEvent(function (data) {
        if (data.status === "success") {
                $("#tabs").tabs();
        }
    });
});
```

**In order to use Session Scope Beans:**

The method `switchPages` in `MyTabs.java` should be `void` and not to return anything, like this

```
    public void switchPages(String selTab) {
    selectedTab = selTab;
}
```

Comment: Very good example. Thank you for the good answer. Looking at the book "Core Java Server faces" I saw that it's possible to create tabs in pure JSF. But is it possible to create JSF tabs with lazy loading and AJAX?

Comment: @PeterPenzov Haven't tried... This is how you do it with Pure JSF & Jquery & Ajax Lazy Loading

Comment: @PeterPenzov isn't my solution fits exactly into your requirements ?

Comment: I would like to ask you for something. This is the code from the book "Core Java Server Faces" which shows how to create tabs. http://www.2shared.com/file/YUSB70Ro/tabbedpane.html  Can you look at it and tell me is it possible to add Ajax support and lazy loading?

Comment: @PeterPenzov will look into it tomorrow... No idea how big is the gap to lazy loading from that example...(if at all) , have you tried my example ?

Comment: Yes I tried your example, I found some bugs. I will continue to work on it for now there are some problems but I will look at them. Thank you!

Comment: @PeterPenzov There were no bugs at all in my project, I can send It to you later on if you want... And if you want to use session scope beans it even easier...

Comment: Ok send me the complete code. upload it here: http://www.2shared.com/ and send me the link.

Comment: Ok, will do it tomorrow... (99% of it already posted here :))

Answer (score 7):

The [Primefaces Tabview](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/tabviewDynamic.jsf) component supports lazy loading.

Quote from the showcase:

> Tab contents can be lazy loaded with ajax as well, when dynamic
>   attribute is set to "true" only the active tab's content will be
>   rendered and clicking on a lazy tab will fetch the tab contents with
>   ajax. This behavior is handy to save bandwith and reduce page size
>   when dealing with tabs having a lot of content.

Quick example from the showcase:

```html
<h:form id="form">  
    <p:tabView id="tabView" dynamic="true" cache="true"> 
      // tabs
    </p:tabView>
</h:form>
```

The `cache` attribute is used to prevent ajax reloading of tab content if you toggle between tabs.

Comment: Yes, this is a possible solution. But is it possible to achieve the same result with pure JSF?

Comment: No. You need at least some additional javascript and css.

Comment: Ok, can I use JQuery with JSF and Lazy loading? Which of the two solutions will require less resources. I will have for example JSF page with 8 tabs. Every tab will have JSF data table with pagination and so on. Which one of the two will be more appropriate for JSF page with many rows of code?

Comment: I don't know. I am not (yet) very experienced with jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a problem at all implement an ajax tab with jQuery UI.

See the documentation of jQuery Tabs with ajax [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#ajax) and click on "view source" to find the code you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the book Core `Java Server Faces third edition` page 339 to see how you can implement simple tabs with `h:panelGrid`.

The output is something like this:

[image]

This is the code example from the book:

```
...
<h:form>
<h:panelGrid styleClass="tabbedPane" columnClasses="displayPanel">
<!-- Tabs -->
<f:facet name="header">
<h:panelGrid columns="4" styleClass="tabbedPaneHeader">
<h:commandLink tabindex="1"
title="#{msgs.jeffersonTooltip}"
styleClass="#{tp.jeffersonStyle}"
actionListener="#{tp.jeffersonAction}">
#{msgs.jeffersonTab}
</h:commandLink>
...
</h:panelGrid>
</f:facet>
<!-- Tabbed pane content -->
<ui:include src="washington.xhtml" />
<ui:include src="roosevelt.xhtml" />
<ui:include src="lincoln.xhtml" />
<ui:include src="jefferson.xhtml" />
</h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
...
```

This is the description:

```
The tabbed pane is implemented with h:panelGrid. Because we do not specify
the columns attribute, the panel has one column. The panel’s header—defined
with an f:facet tag—contains the tabs, which are implemented with another
h:panelGrid that contains h:commandLink tags for each tab. The only row in the panel
contains the content associated with the selected tab.
When a user selects a tab, the associated action listener for the command link is
invoked and modifies the data stored in the backing bean. Because we use a
different CSS style for the selected tab, the styleClass attribute of each h:commandLink
tag is pulled from the backing bean with a value reference expression.
As you can see from the top picture in Figure 8–11, we have used the title
attribute to associate a tooltip with each tab. Another accessibility feature is the
ability to move from one tab to another with the keyboard instead of the
mouse. We implemented that feature by specifying the tabindex attribute for
each h:commandLink.
The content associated with each tab is statically included with the JSP include
directive. For our application, that content is a picture and some text, but
you could modify the included JSF pages to contain any set of appropriate
components. Notice that even though all the JSF pages representing content are
included, only the content associated with the current tab is rendered. That is
achieved with the rendered attribute—for example, jefferson.xhtml looks like this:
Putting It All Together
<h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="presidentDiscussionColumn"
rendered="#{tp.jeffersonCurrent}">
<h:graphicImage value="/images/jefferson.jpg"/>
<span class="tabbedPaneContent">"#{msgs.jeffersonDiscussion}"</span>
</h:panelGrid>
Figure 8–12 shows the directory structure for the tabbed pane application and
Listings 8–14 through 8–17 show the most important files.
```

Unfortunately I don't know how to add lazy loading and AJAX support to this code.